# Angularjs return issue in response of $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I made a function for managing data sending to server side. I want to **return** response of `$http` when it success.

My controller: (When I call the function)

```
var myResponse = sendData(inputValueArray, url, onSuc, onErr, $http);
// Nothing happen here:
alert(myResponse);
```

My function for sending data:

```
function sendData(inputArray, url, onSuccess, onErr, $http) {
var serverResponse = "";
$http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: {
          myData: inputArray
        },
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    })
.success(function(response) {
    if (response.res == true) {
        onSuccess();
        serverResponse = response;
    }
    else {
        onErr();
    }
})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    onErr();
});
return serverResponse;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning `serverResponse` before it has any data from the call back. Instead, try something like this:

```
function sendData(inputArray, url, onSuccess, onErr, $http) {
  var serverResponse = "";
  $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';

  return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: {
          myData: inputArray
        },
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    });
}
```

And then you use it like this

```
sendData
.success(function(response) {
    if (response.res == true) {
        onSuccess();
        serverResponse = response;
        alert(serverResponse);   // ************
    }
    else {
        onErr();
    }
})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    onErr();
});
```

Comment: I want to get the response to do a lot of things with it in `controller`. So not simply an alert. Also it's more flexible for me. Thanks :)